# Finding the possible number of subsets that can arise out of a given set

Tags: combinatorics

Let S be a set of natural number from 1 to n.
What is the number of possible pairs of the form (A,B) such that A is a subset of B , for subsets A and B of S ?

My attempt - I that the total number of subsets for the whole set of n numbers will be $2^n$ , so I thought of adding the cases while n ranges from 0 to n. 
Hence my answer turns out to be $2^n*2 - 1$
While the correct answer is $3^n$

What am I doing wrong ?
What is the correct approach ?

Comment: I can’t tell what thought process led you to your result. For a correct approach, note that each element of $S$ must belong to exactly one of the sets $A$, $B\setminus A$, and $S\setminus B$.

Comment: Got it ! 
Thanks. 

What I was doing wrong was that i was forgetting that if i am selecting a set of only n-1 elements from S then there are ${n \choose n-1}$ ways of doing so . 
Similarly for the other sets . 
Once I do that and sum it up we get the result $3^n$

Comment: Ah, now I see; yes, that’s another perfectly good way to think about it.

Comment: @Brian M.Scott , It would be very helpful if you could tell mw how to use your approach to compute the result.It's always better knowing more than just one way to solve a problem :)

Comment: To build a specific pair $\langle A,B\rangle$ with $A\subseteq B$ you can imagine going through $S$ one element at a time and deciding whether that element is in $A$, in $B$ but not in $A$, or not in $B$. That’s a $3$-way choice for each of $n$ elements of $S$, so it can be made in $3^n$ different ways. Each of those ways corresponds to exactly one acceptable pair $\langle A,B\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks so much , this is a much more elegant way to solve this.
If you could put in the previous comment as an answer , I would mark the question as answered and it will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a specific pair $\langle A,B\rangle$ with $A\subseteq B$ you can imagine going through $S$ one element at a time and deciding whether that element is in $A$, in $B$ but not in $A$, or not in $B$. That’s a $3$-way choice for each of $n$ elements of $S$, so it can be made in $3^n$ different ways. Each of those ways corresponds to exactly one acceptable pair $\langle A,B\rangle$.